# GetOpenFileNameW results in FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME, or CDERR_INITIALIZATION if I call GetOpenFileNameA

Tags: windows, d

Here's the code using `GetOpenFileNameW`:

```
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import std.stdio, std.string, std.utf;

pragma(lib, "comdlg32");

// Fill in some missing holes in core.sys.windows.windows.
extern (Windows) DWORD CommDlgExtendedError();
enum OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = 0x001000;

void main()
{
    auto buf = new wchar[1024];

    OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
    ofn.lStructSize = ofn.sizeof;
    ofn.lpstrFile = buf.ptr;
    ofn.nMaxFile = buf.length;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = null;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    BOOL retval = GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn);
    if (retval == 0) {
        // Get 0x3002 for W and 0x0002 for A. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646916(v=vs.85).aspx )
        throw new Exception(format("GetOpenFileName failure: 0x%04X.", CommDlgExtendedError()));
    }

    writeln(buf);
}
```

This results in `FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME`, but I don't see any non-optional strings that I haven't filled in. And here's the code (only differences shown) for `GetOpenFileNameA`:

```
auto buf = new char[1024];

OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
// ...
BOOL retval = GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn);
```

This results in `CDERR_INITIALIZATION`, and the only elaboration MSDN gives me is

```
The common dialog box function failed during initialization. 
This error often occurs when sufficient memory is not available.
```

This is on Windows 7 64 bit, DMD v2.059.

Comment: There are lots of members of OPENFILENAMEW that you haven't explicitly initialized.  Are you sure the compiler is initializing them to the values you expect?  Can you use a debugger to look at the structure at runtime?

Comment: D zeroes initialisations unless you explicitly ask it _not_ to, so all optional members are `null` or `0` (their `.init` value). The problem was that for the buffer, `wchar.init` was not what I thought it was. >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`buf` has to be zeroed completely. The problem here is that `wchar.init == wchar.max` (for error detection reasons), so your array is essentially 1024 instances of `wchar.max`. A simple `buf[] = 0;` should fix that.

Comment: Well _that_ explains the different errors (UTF-16 invalid string vs ANSI string full of whatever 0xFF is in the current codepage). I should've thought of checking that. Thanks!